# Sometimes HTML element doesn't display value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using a $.get method to populate some data. If this data exists, then .show() the html element and populate them accordingly.

[image]

If there is no data, then the page should look as above.

[image]

If there IS data, then the page should display the html elements being populated as shown.

My issue is that sometimes, even if there IS data to be displayed, the elements show, but they aren't being populated properly, as seen here:

[image]

The console shows that the data is being retrieved properly, seen here:

[image]

Even weirder is that, in the example where the data isn't loaded properly, the price loads just fine. Don't understand why price is ok, but disabled drop-down menus don't display anything sometimes.

Here is the code I use to load the data:

```
Here's the code:
$.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Servlet_Stock', {PRDCODE: sParam.PRDCODE, SFC: 'GET_PRD_DETAIL'}, function(data) {
                    var arrData = data.object1[0];
                    //console.log("arrData: ",arrData);
                    defUOM = arrData.stk_baseuomcode;
                    $('#modalCode').val(arrData.stk_stockcode);
                    $('#modalDesc').val(arrData.stk_desc);
                    
                    if (arrData.MinPriceBase.length !== 0) {
                        $("#priceAdd").hide();
                        //$('#minPriceActive').trigger('click');
                        $('#minPriceActive').prop('checked',true);
                        console.log(arrData.MinPrice, " + ", arrData.MinPriceBase, " + ", arrData.MinPriceUOM);

                        $("#minPriceActive").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#minPrice").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#ddlMinPrc").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#ddlUOM").prop("disabled", true);
                        
                        $("#mbField").show();
                        $("#mbField2").show();
                        $('#minPrice').val(arrData.MinPrice);
                        $('#ddlMinPrc').val(arrData.MinPriceBase);
                        $('#ddlUOM').val(arrData.MinPriceUOM);
                    } else {
                        //$("#tblSearch").hide();
                        $("#minPriceActive").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#priceAdd").hide();
                    }
```

Not sure what's wrong with the code i've written..

Comment: Why would you not provide the code as text? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: The error messages in your console look significant.

Comment: The error messages in the console can be ignored, those are from another part of the site im not working on

Comment: My assumption is that the master data that are populating both the select/drop down is not loaded properly in some cases.

Comment: @SangSuantak can't be, i can print the data in console 100% of the time, its something else im pretty sure. i think the problem has something to do with the drop down menus because price loads every time (edit: when i say "load" i mean populated properly)

Comment: Just so that we are on the same page, when I mean the master data, I mean the select items (not only the selected item). What I'm assuming is that you first populate the select items from a master data, and then set the selected item based on what you've shown in the code.

Comment: yes, if  by select items you mean the values in the drop down list, then yeah they are populated (i.e. there are other options in the drop down list), but the display value is set to the values that $.get retrieves for both drop downs

Comment: Are you *sure* those error messages aren’t related?  You’re having problems with drop downs, and your drop-down code is throwing errors…  I’d think it worthwhile spending some time investigating that as a possible source.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yep, the error messages are not related. they pop up when i enter the home page of the site, the drop-down is not the source of the errors you see (thinking back i shouldve just cropped it out or something lol)

Comment: One would expect those errors to show up immediately on page load; that doesn’t rule them out as the source of your current problem.

Answer (score 1):

These look like custom select fields, not the ones provided natively by the browser. This is confirmed by an error in your console output indicating that JS parser encountered an error parsing the code. I would suggest first checking if select2.min.js file you're loading is not corrupted.

Not strictly related to question, but do note that such libraries usually work by hiding an original element and then generating it's own HTML structure on top of it. Because of that, additional attention is required as to which elements you operate with. While things like options and select states are usually synchronized between the two, others, like hover events and optgroups, might be not.

You can check if your code is running correctly by going through browser inspect and finding the original `<select>` and un-hiding it, or simply removing select2 from list of libraries loaded, to see if it behaves the way you expect.

Comment: The error messages in the console can be ignored, those appear in another part of the site that doesn't involve the work I'm doing.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I found a workaround. Since drop down menus don't work properly, i've created a text box instead. So now the values display in a text box, rather than the disabled drop down list. Still don't understand why populating drop down menus dont work so well, but at least this method is more consistent.

Here is the final look, if you're curious:

[image]